How to layout 2 widgets, one on top of the other in Flutter Stack?
I have a CustomPaint that paints an image with a certain width and height. I want to create a semitransparent overlay widget which will hold stickers on top of the CustomePaint widget. How can I properly size the overlay widget to be the same size as the CustomPaint widget? Here is the code snippet.
Stack(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[
    FittedBox(
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      child: Center(
        child: CustomPaint(
          size: Size(1024, 768), // Set the size of the CustomPaint
          painter: _painter,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Positioned.fill(
            return Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Container(
              width: ??
              height: ??
              color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.5), // Adjust opacity for visibility
            ),
          );
        },
       ),
  ],
)


Does this work for you? (Untested code)
const painterSize = Size(1024, 768);
return Center(
  child: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      SizedBox.fromSize(
        size: painterSize,
        child: CustomPaint(
          size: painterSize, // Set the size of the CustomPaint
          painter: _painter,
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox.fromSize(
        size: painterSize,
          child: ColoredBox(
        color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.5),
      ))
    ],
  ),
);


No, that doesn't work. The ColoredBox covers the entire Stack widget which is in a Column. I want it to cover only the Customer Paint.

@jdevp2 Does it work now? Since you know the size of the widget, you can just use it for the ColoredBox.
